# Navigation bar gap issue in iPhone Mini

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, navigationbar

Navigation bar gap issue in iPhone mini

Only in iPhoneMini This issue occurred.

[image]

How to resolve this gap in iPhone mini?

```
var window: UIWindow?
var mainNavController = UINavigationController()

static var shared: SceneDelegate {
    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let sceneDelegate = windowScene?.delegate as! SceneDelegate
    return sceneDelegate
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    navigateToHome()
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}

func navigateToHome(){
    let dashboardController = UIStoryboard.identifier(.Dashboard).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! TabBarController
    mainNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboardController)
    mainNavController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    window?.rootViewController = mainNavController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

}

// At HomeViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
}
    func setupUI(){
        setTitle(text: "Home")
        setNavigationBar()
}
    func setNavigationBar(color: UIColor = .appThemeColor){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = color
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.hide_NavigationBar_BottonLine()
        navigationController?.statusBar(colour: color)
    }

    func hide_NavigationBar_BottonLine(){
        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your current code? Or better a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @aheze Updated with current code

Answer (score 0):

Issue related to status bar height

Below extension will resolved the issue.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func statusBar(colour color : UIColor) {
        let statusBarFrame: CGRect
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            statusBarFrame = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero
        } else {
            statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        }

        // iPhone Mini Status Bar height Issue fixed
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
            .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
            .compactMap({$0})
            .first?.windows
            .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
        let height = UIApplication.shared.statusBarHeight
        let topInset: CGFloat = keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? height
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
        statusBarView.frame.size.height = topInset
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = color
        view.addSubview(statusBarView)
    }

}

// Status Bar Height
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
        connectedScenes
            .compactMap {
                $0 as? UIWindowScene
            }
            .compactMap {
                $0.statusBarManager
            }
            .map {
                $0.statusBarFrame
            }
            .map(\.height)
            .max() ?? 0
    }
}
```